# npm install -g but always installed locally

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using window, and my npm always install my package locally even though I add -g flag after the command: `npm install gulp -g`

How can I solve this problem? I want to share the node module among projects.

```
>npm -v
3.10.3

>node -v
v6.7.0

>npm list -g
`-- (empty)
```

Comment: did you try using the options immediately after `npm`?  i.e.   `npm -g install gulp`

Comment: yes, i tried but still fail

Comment: Can you type `gulp --version`?

Comment: remove your local gulp once or delete node_modules, if nothing is there. Reinstall using sudo.

Comment: ``gulp --version`` > ``[11:05:42] CLI version 3.9.1`` ``[11:05:42] Local version 3.9.1``

Comment: I've tried many times reinstalling node_modules, and the problem is still here.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a broken alias in your shell. Try running:
`\npm i -g gulp`

to verify what path you are using for npm run:
`type npm`
Or 
`Which npm`